# Change the spacing of a pandas plot?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting a time-series graph using pandas, my data looks like this

```
1986-87  334
1987-88  331
1988-89  352
1989-90  380
1990-91  386
1991-92  386
1992-93  390
1993-94  403
1994-95  406
```

My code looks like this

```
playercount = pd.DataFrame(t.groupby('season').size())
playercount.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want more zoomed version than this. Currently my one pixel consists of 10 years, I want to modify it to make it more fine-grained i.e. 5 or fewer years. What parameters can I change to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to change your grid spacing?

Comment: @Alexander, yes. I want it to be more fine-grained , more zoomed-in in a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the grid spacing, try adjusting the parameter `n` below:

```
n = 5
playercount.plot(xticks=playercount.index[::n], grid=True)
```

It means that you are using every `n'th` index value as a tick mark on the x-axis.

If your index is not a timestamp but is a string, then this should work.

```
playercount.plot(xticks=[i for i in range(len(playercount.index)) if not i % n], grid=True)
```

Comment: I am getting the follwing error ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2014-15. Do I have to convert the data from 2011-12 to 2011.